# ¿Cómo deshabilitar un item de un DataGridViewComboBoxCell al seleccionarlo?

Tags: vb.net, gridview

Que tal, tengo un GridView el cual tengo una columna tipo ComboBox, lo que quiero hacer es que cada vez que seleccione un item del combo este ya no se pueda elegir en otra fila de la columna.

Comment: Se retiró la etiqueta visual-basic porque es ambigua y se ha sugerido su quemado. Véase https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1045/65